# iPhone SDK : Multiple images upload to server with SOAP request

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, soap, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I know very well that you may count this thread as duplicate just because multiple times this question was asked in different ways. I did not find any solution from the existing questions on this forum and thus i'm going to make a new thread.

Here, I've a code for uploading multiple images at a time. So, please note down the sentence that is "multiple images upload".

I want to upload 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 images along with some text parameters and the issue that i'm facing is "same image is uploaded multiple times" mean single image having multiple times on server.

Example :

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MultipleImageUpload",soapAction];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[theRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[theRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:60];
[theRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",BOUNDARY_MULTIPART_IMAGE];
[theRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

//parameter SecurityCode
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BOUNDARY_MULTIPART_IMAGE] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"SecurityCode\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[SEC_CODE dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//parameter LoggedInUserID
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BOUNDARY_MULTIPART_IMAGE] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"LoggedInUserID\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@“23433” dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//parameter Device
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BOUNDARY_MULTIPART_IMAGE] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Device\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@“iPhone” dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

for (int i=0; i<[arrImgs count]; i++) {
    UIImage* image = [arrImgs objectAtIndex:i];
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BOUNDARY_MULTIPART_IMAGE] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product_photo\"; filename=\"%d.jpg\"\r\n", i] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imgData]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BOUNDARY_MULTIPART_IMAGE] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the request
[theRequest setHTTPBody:body];
return theRequest;
```

Please let me know if anyone has the solution for this one ..

**Thanks,**

**Nilesh M. Prajapati**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone,
But i got the solution. Actually, I have to set dynamic filename in below lines.. I have to set "product_photo" as a dynamic string having random number like "product_photo1" or "product_photo2", etc..

```
for (int i=0; i<[arrImgs count]; i++) 
{
   UIImage* image = [arrImgs objectAtIndex:i];
   NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BOUNDARY_MULTIPART_IMAGE] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product_photo%d\"; filename=\"%d.png\"\r\n", i,i] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [body appendData:imgData];
   [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```